# OnCollisonEnter2D Unity c# script for 2D collisions not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2d platformer. I have an object that when the player collides with it, the game restarts. For some reason it doesn't work. I set a simple `Debug.Log` statement to test it. But, it just doesn't work. Here's the code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collisionInfo)
    
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Lose")
        {
            Debug.Log("lose");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot with us, that shows the the collider component of the object and all of it's properties.

Comment: Make sure both have a collider, neither is set to isTrigger, and at least one (if memory serves) has a RigidBody.

Comment: Thanks, I found an answer. I'm sorry I didnt see the answers until now.